# How to Handle NameError for multiple Variable by Try Except in Python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, try-catch, nameerror

I have 6 variables and trying to concatenate them. I am using try except method to handle the NameError.

Here is my code

```
try:
    var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6

except NameError:
    var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5
```

I can handle first time NameError for var6 using except NameError

But How Can I handle more NameError for var5, and var4?

I am trying like this but got an error

```
try:
    var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6

except NameError:
    var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 

except NameError:
    var1 + var2 + var3 + var4

except NameError:
    var1 + var2 + var3
```

How can I handle multiple NameError?

Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense - how do you not know which variables are defined? Unless you're doing ["variable variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761), and you've shown exactly why that's a bad idea, or maybe you're defining them conditionally (also a bad idea).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731 - there will be a solution, but to the X not the Y.